# HTML Form calling PHP returns blank

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

My html form is:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="AddEmail.php" method="GET>

<table>
<tr>
<td>Email Address</td>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>Surname</td>
<td><td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="text" name="emailAddress" value="example@email.com"> </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="firstName" value="First Name"> </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="surname" value="Surname"> </td>
<td> <input type="submit"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and the php that it is calling is:

```
$Email = $_GET["email"]
$firstName = $_GET["fName"]
$surName = $_GET["surname"]


$sql = "INSERT INTO emailaddress (EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES ($Email, $firstName, $surName)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>`
```

It is meant to pass the inputted information on to a database. It is connecting to the database without an issue when I use already use pre-created values for it to input, but as soon as I try and get it to use inputted values and call the php it just returns with a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the semicolons at the end of the line for the first 3 lines of the php file.

A blank page is typical for a syntax error. Whenever a blank page is displayed for no good reason put the following lines at the top of your php file and you should see the php error displayed.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Besides that:

- You will also receive a SQL error because you are not enclosing the php variables in quotes when you construct the query. You should REALLY consider escaping all user submitted data.
- $_GET["email"] should be $_GET["emailAddress"] as set in the form
- $_GET["fName"] should be $_GET["firstName"] as set in the form
- Consider using the html attribute "placeholder" instead of writing the hint as a value.

Also, what user3590911 said about the quote

Comment: user3590911 just said to add the closing `"` which would technically be correct.

Comment: I don't know why but i thought he changed GET to POST :) my bad

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="AddEmail.php" method="GET>
```

should be:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="AddEmail.php" method="GET">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="AddEmail.php" method="GET>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Email Address</td>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="text" name="email_address" value="example@email.com" >   </td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="firstName" value="First Name"> </td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="surname" value="Surname"> </td>
      <td> <input type="submit"> </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</form>

    <?php 
          $Email = $_GET["email_address"]
          $firstName = $_GET["firstName"]
          $surName = $_GET["surname"]

          $sql = "INSERT INTO emailaddress (EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName)  VALUES ($Email,$firstName, $surName)";
          $queries = $conn->query($sql);
          if ( $queries ) {
              echo "New record created successfully";
          } 
          else 
          {
              die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        $conn->close();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="AddEmail.php" method="GET>
```

to

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="AddEmail.php" method="post>
```

Comment: The PHP code is obviously using the $_GET variables, so changing it to a post isn't going to help.  You've also not added in the missing close quote from the method attributes value (`method="post">`)